# How can one derive the Hamiltonian-function out of a differential equation of second order that describes the motion of a pendulum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

How can a Hamiltonian-function be derived out of a differential equation of second order describing a pendulum motion as for example:

$$\theta^{(2)}(t) = A*\theta + cos(B*\omega),$$

where the superscript number denotes the 2nd and 1st derivative respectively. What is the Hamiltonian function corresponding to this?

Comment: I assume the omega is supposed to be a theta?

Comment: the omega should be the first derivative of theta